# Spresense SDKに、Static Library (.a)を追加する方法は

Tags: spresense, makefile

元はCで書かれた、Static Library (.a)とヘッダーファイルがあり、
これをSpresense SDKで使いたいです
どうすれば良いでしょうか？

■(例) Static Library (.a)とヘッダーファイル
header_file1.h
header_file2.h
 :
header_file5.h
myStatic_lib.a　　　※ Cortex-M4 hard_float

Spresense SDKに追加する場所は、
　hellow_worldサンプル内に追加、
　Nuttx側のどこか
　または、その他
かと思っております

Makefileを編集する力があればできるのかも。。

hello
┝ .built
┝ .depend
┝ hello_main.c
┝ hello_main.o
┝ make.deps
┝ make.dep
┗ Makefile

■make.depファイル
hello_main.o: hello_main.c \
 /Users/*username*/spresense/sdk/bsp/include/sdk/config.h \
　：
 /Users/*username*/spresense/nuttx/include/nuttx/addrenv.h
 インクルードファイルはこのあたりに追加？

■Makefile
-include $(TOPDIR)/Make.defs
-include $(SDKDIR)/Make.defs

CONFIG_HELLO_PRIORITY ?= SCHED_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
CONFIG_HELLO_STACKSIZE ?= 2048

APPNAME = hello
PRIORITY = $(CONFIG_HELLO_PRIORITY)
STACKSIZE = $(CONFIG_HELLO_STACKSIZE)

MAINSRC = hello_main.c
ASRCS =
CSRCS = $(filter-out $(MAINSRC),$(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard */*.c))
CXXSRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard */*.cpp) $(wildcard *.cxx) $(wildcard */*.cxx)

CFLAGS += $(foreach inc,$(wildcard ../*/include),-I$(inc))

CXXFLAGS += $(foreach inc,$(wildcard ../*/include),-I$(inc))

CONFIG_HELLO_PROGNAME ?= hello$(EXEEXT)
PROGNAME = $(CONFIG_HELLO_PROGNAME)

include $(APPDIR)/Application.mk

自分にはちょっとハードルが高そう。。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コンパイル済みのライブラリを取り込むときは `externals` に入れるのが良いと思います。

`externals` フォルダ以下に `xxx` というディレクトリを新規作成して、そこにライブラリ(`libxxx.a`)とヘッダファイル(`xxx.h`)を置きます。`xxx` は適当に読み替えてください。

> spresense/externals/xxx
>   |-- Kconfig
>   |-- LibIncludes.mk
>   |-- LibTarget.mk
>   |-- libxxx.a
>   `-- xxx.h

Kconfig, LibIncludes.mk, LibTarget.mk ファイルを用意して、それぞれ以下のように書きます。

■ Kconfig

```
config EXTERNALS_XXX
    bool "XXX Library"
    default n
```

■ LibIncludes.mk

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_EXTERNALS_XXX),y)
CFLAGS   += ${shell $(INCDIR) $(INCDIROPT) "$(CC)" "$(SDKDIR)/../externals/xxx"}
CXXFLAGS += ${shell $(INCDIR) $(INCDIROPT) "$(CC)" "$(SDKDIR)/../externals/xxx"}
endif
```

■ LibTarget.mk

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_EXTERNALS_XXX),y)
EXTLIBS += lib$(DELIM)libxxx$(LIBEXT)
XXXDIRS += $(EXTERNAL_DIR)$(DELIM)xxx
endif

lib$(DELIM)libxxx$(LIBEXT): $(XXXDIRS)$(DELIM)libxxx$(LIBEXT)
    $(Q) install $< $@
```

SDK Configuration で Externals -> XXX Library を選択して CONFIG_EXTERNALS_XXX を有効にしておきます。そうすれば、例えば、hello_main.c へ `#include <xxx.h>` を追加して libxxx.a の関数を呼び出すことが可能になります。

これら `externals/mqtt` を参考にしてみました。

Answer (score 0):

externalsフォルダの活用、とても参考になりました！
externals**直下**のKconfigの編集が必要でしたので追記しておきます

> spresense/externals
>   |-- Kconfig

■ Kconfig
　下記、sourceの行を追加する。(xxxは読み替え必要)

```
menu "Externals"
 : (省略)
source "/home/*username*/spresense/externals/xxx/Kconfig"
endmenu # Externals
```

これで、SDK Configuration で Externals -> XXX Library　がGUIで見える様になりました