# SPRESENSE SDKで 自作ライブラリの作成方法について教えてください

Tags: spresense

タイトル通りです。
■ 環境
・OS
Ubuntu:18.04
・ツール
VSCODE
SPRESENSE SDK

■ 状況
VSCODE上でSPRESENS SDKによるプログラミングを楽しんでいますが、
自作した複数アプリケーションで共通で使うライブラリはどのようにしたら使用可能なのでしょうか。

ワークスペース上でフォルダを作成"myDriver"などにライブラリファイルを格納
各アプリケーションからライブラリをインクルードすると、インクルードエラーが出てしまいます。

色々試してみたのですが、上手く行かないので質問させて頂きました。
どなたかご存じの方がいらっしゃれば、ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

過去のスタックオーバーフローの投稿で、既に参照されているかもしれませんが...

[Spresense SDKに、Static Library (.a)を追加する方法は](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61027/spresense-sdk%e3%81%ab-static-library-a%e3%82%92%e8%bf%bd%e5%8a%a0%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%af)

static library を `externals` 以下で作成するという方法です。
SDK2.0 から `LibTarget.mk` -> `Library.mk` へと若干構成が変わってそうですが、
参考になったりしないでしょうか。